# Join two txt files

Tags: linux, file

Using Linux: *.txt files

file1

```
HOUSAM000001189870 1012212222011212100020102102112011002200111112012220110 ....... 
HOUSAM000001213135 2012012000120120102010201002102111200122201100222201102 .......
HOUSAM000001237057 0012011222010210120120122210000101112000222210102010201 .......
HOUSAM000001239242 2210120111010010100100022001111000010220010102010201022 .......
```

file2

```
HOUSAM000001189870     
HOUSAM000001237057
```

Output file

```
HOUSAM000001189870 1012212222011212100020102102112011002200111112012220110 .......
HOUSAM000001237057 0012011222010210120120122210000101112000222210102010201 .......
```

Comment: That's not joining. If you joined the files, the output would have everything from both files.

Comment: I think he means joining in the data-base sense of the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } $1 in array { print $1, array[$1] }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Results:

```
4046 200344
4050 200001
4047 200122
```

***Edit: using real data:***

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$0; next } $1 in array { print array[$1] }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Results:

```
HOUSAM000001189870 1012212222011212100020102102112011002200111112012220110 ....... 
HOUSAM000001237057 0012011222010210120120122210000101112000222210102010201 .......
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not work with my real data. May be because it is huge or because some numbers in the first column are mixed of numbers and litters like this: WEO215H1254896 .... so any idea?

Comment: @amhemadahmad: Would you be able to post some of your data where it is different from your sample data? Alternatively, if you can upload it to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/), perhaps I can help you some more. HTH.

Comment: @amhemadahmad: Please see my edited answer. It should now work correctly. HTH.

Comment: @amhemadahmad: What is the error message you're receiving when run on the sample data you have posted? Also, what are the results of `awk --version | head -n 1`? The code is working correctly for me.

Comment: No error message, but the output file is empty ... GNU Awk 3.1.5

Comment: So what version of `awk` are you using? Also, please make sure that `file2.txt` exists. That may be the reason you're not getting any output. If you can, upload the files to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/) so I can take a look.

Comment: @amhemadahmad: Did you manage to get this to work on the sample data you've posted?

Comment: @amhemadahmad: So what's so different about the real data? I will delete my answer if we can't get this resolved soon.

Comment: I dont know! If I know, I can tell you ... but really I dont

Comment: May be because the data is really huge. Each line has more 45,000 characters.

Comment: @amhemadahmad: That's a lot of character's `awk` would be adding to memory! Maybe there's an upper limit of `awk` that I don't know about. Alternatively, you may need a bigger computer. Sorry I cannot be much more help. Perhaps one of the other solutions listed here will work better for you.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I found out what was the problem !! the first column in the two file does not match exactly .. like this   HOUSAM000001189870 & HOUSA000001189870 so know it works perfectly ... thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: @amhemadahmad: No problem. Glad we got it sorted out. Don't forget to accept an answer if it has helped you. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -F -f file2 file1 > file3
```

If you need to match only the first column and you can change the patterns file you can add ^ to the front of each line and treat that file as regex (remove the first -F). So...

file2:

```
^4046
^4050
^4047
```

Then:

```
grep -f file2 file1 > file3
```

If you can't change the patterns file or if it is generated outside of your control then Serge's answer is the best one.

Comment: Works without the additional -F @Serge what is it doing?

Comment: I wrote in the comment to the edit. While -f works, the -F tells to treat rows in file2 as fixed strings, not as regex pattrens

Comment: I don't think this is going to be accurate.  Won't it match the keys in the 2nd field as well as the first?

Comment: `-F` means use fixed strings, instead of regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `join` command in conjunction with `sort`:

```
$ join <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)
4046 200344
4047 200122
4050 200001
```

Comment: while this works, it will produce the sorted output. The OP posted the differently ordered result.

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
sed 's/^/^/;s/$/[[:space:]]' file2 | grep -f - file1 > file3
```